# How to trigger validation on reactive form through input decorator?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a validation directive that takes an input from a parent component. The validation is passed only when the input is true. So whenever an input changes, I don't know how to trigger validation method in the directive

I have a sample working [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-reactive-form-validation-zasxcg?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) on stackblitz for the purpose of demonstrating the issue

```
//As you can see the appRouteValidator is passing an input randomNumber

<input type="random" appRouteValidator [randomOption]="randomNumber" 
formControlName="random" class="form-control"/>
```

The validate method here is I want to call on every time the input changes,

```
export class DemoValidatorDirective {
  @Input() randomOption: Boolean;


  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.randomOption.currentValue) {
        //---------------------------------> Should trigger validate method
    }
  }
  constructor() { }
  // This should be called when it receives an input
  validate(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any; } {
    console.log('validation method called');
    if (control && (control.value !== null || control.value !== undefined)) {
      const randomField = control.value;
          if (!randomField || !this.randomOption) {
            return {
              'validationError': 'invalid random number'
            }; 
          }
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: input is true means?

Comment: @Input() randomOption: Boolean; it receives a boolean.

Comment: Ok, please correct me if I am wrong, based on your randomOption value you want to validate the 'random' control? if the value is true then it should validate otherwise not.

Comment: Question is I want to trigger the validate method when the directive receives the input.

Answer (score 0):

for manually calling validation method of Respective FormControl, you need call the AbstractControl class method of 'updateValueAndValidity' based on your validation rules.

I have added two lines in the generateRandomNumber method, here is the code:

```js
generateRandomNumber() {
      let randomNumber: any = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
      this.randomNumber = randomNumber % 2 === 0;
      if(this.randomNumber)
        this.registerForm.controls.random.updateValueAndValidity();
      console.log('random number', this.randomNumber);
    }
```

Please refer the working example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-reactive-form-validation-wbqwv7?file=app/app.component.ts)

Please let me know if you have any question.